# An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

```
return this.RedirectToAction<MerchantController>(x => x.Edit(merchantId));
```

Where edit had a second, nullable argument.

Why is this?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The [underlying expression tree API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call.aspx) does not support optional arguments.

For IL-compiled code the C# compiler inserts the default values at compile time (hard-coded), because the CLR does not support calling methods with optional arguments either when the arguments are not provided explicitly.

Comment: Does this somehow include overloads? I was getting this when I made an overload. Something like void Blah(string a) and void Blah(object a). When I tried to MOQ out a call to the version with object, it gave me this error.

Comment: Overloads are fully supported in the sense that a particular overload will be hard-coded into the tree.

Comment: Pretty cryptic error message, but this answer showed the way, I had optional parameter with default value on the method is was trying to mock.

Answer (score 302):

Had the same message when trying to use Mock.setup to mock a method with multiple default parameters. I just had to add the additional parameters in the lambda.

```
void someMethod(string arg1 = "", string arg2 = "")

mockedObject.Setup(x => x.someMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
```

Comment: Depending on use case also ...`x.someMethod(default,default)`... can be used.

Answer (score 6):

Error: 'an exception tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses option arguments'

Why: Because you are not providing the optional parameters when calling the method. Mainly you get this with .net core when using IAsyncProxy service object.

Fix: Pass all the optional parameters value, you may use default value if you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to test that a method that has default parameters is called without any argument passed, in that case:

`myMock.someMethod(default,default)`

can work

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with it by adding the optional parameter with a value . It worked. The same thing happened when I tried mocking while doing a setup .

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with this:

```
var values = from ac in _dbContext.Entities<AuthCompany>()
                                 from uc in _dbContext.Entities<UserCompany>()
                                            .Where(x => x.CompanyID == ac.CompanyID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select ac;
```

I fixed it by extracting the `DbQuery`s into their own variables:

```
var authCompanyEntities = _dbContext.Entities<AuthCompany>();
var userCompanyEntities = _dbContext.Entities<UserCompany>();

var values = from ac in authCompanyEntities
             from uc in userCompanyEntities.Where(x => x.CompanyID == ac.CompanyID).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select ac;
```