# How do I get default values of optional parameters?

Tags: c#, constructor, default-value, optional-parameters

I have a constructor with optional parameters. **I would like to have an expression** to invoke that constructor without providing the optional arguments (I mean let the object be constructed with default values of the parameters).

I read here *[An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum)* that this is not possible.

I mean

```
var ctorInfo = getIt;
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.New(ctorInfo)).Compile();
```

fails with `System.TypeInitializationException`.

Alright, I will pass the default values. But how do I get the default values of the parameters?

```
ctorInfo.GetParameters().Select(??
```

*Motive: Learning purpose, no real world application.*

**Edit:** Edited out *expression-tree* tag since its not in the context of building expressions, valid in general too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `ParameterInfo.RawDefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.rawdefaultvalue.aspx):

```
ctorInfo.GetParameters().Select( p => p.RawDefaultValue );
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: Corrected property because:

> This property [DefaultValue] is used only in the execution context. In the
>   reflection-only context, use the RawDefaultValue property instead.

Comment: Yes it does! Do you know the difference between `DefaultValue` and `RawDefaultValue`?

Comment: Not exactly. I just gave a look up on msdn. However I assume `RawDefaultValue` is right for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, I made it a separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185826/difference-between-parameterinfo-defaultvalue-and-parameterinfo-rawdefaultvalue