# Unexpected difference in DefaultValue and RawDefaultValue for Enum parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums, system.reflection

Consider the following example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var par in typeof(A).GetMethod("Method").GetParameters())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Def {0}, RawDef {1}",
                par.DefaultValue, par.RawDefaultValue);
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    public void Method(int a = 5, B b = B.b){}
}
enum B
{
    a = 0, b = 1
}
```

According to the documentation of [`RawDefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.rawdefaultvalue.aspx) and [`DefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue.aspx), with support from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185826/difference-between-parameterinfo-defaultvalue-and-parameterinfo-rawdefaultvalue%5C), these two methods of accessing the default value should return the same data.

But instead, I get the following  output:

```
Def 5, RawDef 5
Def b, RawDef 1
```

So, apparently, `RawDefaultValue` drops the information about the parameter being an enum type.

My question: is it a bug or is it justified by another part of the documentation?

Fun fact: on Mono it returns

```
Def 5, RawDef 5
Def b, RawDef b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***tl;dr: It's not a bug it's a feature...***

As you can see in the documentation, [`RawDefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.rawdefaultvalue.aspx) supports *reflection-only context* while [`DefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue.aspx) does not.

Now if we inspect the source code of both of the method we will see that it calls `System.Reflection.MdConstant`'s method `GetValue` method with `bool raw` flag.

Since `System.Reflection` wants to provide you the 'best' information in can depending on the context it is in, it would rather provide you an `enum` instead of a raw value (The raw value can be concluded from the `enum` field, the opposite doesn't work).

Now we can see in `System.Reflection.MdConstant.GetValue` that:

```
if (fieldType.IsEnum && raw == false)
{
    ...
    switch (corElementType) //The actual enum value
    {
        ...
        case CorElementType.I4:
            defaultValue = *(int*)&buffer;
            break;
        ...
    }
    return RuntimeType.CreateEnum(fieldType, defaultValue);
}
```

Which in your case returns `B.b // = 1`.

But calling `RawDefaultValue` makes that flag `false` which makes it:

```
switch (corElementType)
{
    ...
    case CorElementType.I4:
        return *(int*)&buffer;
    ...
}
```

Which in your case returns `1`.

If you try to invoke `System.RuntimeType.CreateEnum` using `Reflection` (because it's internal), with a *reflection-only context* loaded `Assembly` you will get an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
//Change to 'Assembly.Load' so the last line will not throw.
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("DllOfB");

Type runtimeType = Type.GetType("System.RuntimeType");
MethodInfo createEnum = runtimeType.GetMethod("CreateEnum", /*BindingFlags*/);

MethodInfo getRuntimeType = typeof(RuntimeTypeHandle).GetMethod("GetRuntimeType", /*BindingFlags*/);
Type bType = assembly.GetType("DllOfB.B");

//Throws 'InvalidOperationException':
object res = createEnum.Invoke(null, new [] { getRuntimeType.Invoke(bType.TypeHandle, new object[]{}), 1 });
```

As for `Mono` supporting the return of `B.b` from `RawDefaultValue` , ***It means that `Mono` doesn't support `DefaultValue` for reflection-only context*** or that it can somehow create an instance of a `Type` from an `Assembly` which is possibly in a different architecture - which is very unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed analysis. Impossibility to create an enum in reflection only context makes sense. The fact that it works on Mono is, indeed, only to be considered as a "fun fact". My experience shows that many things tend to work on Mono, but are prohibited on .NET :) Makes writing for both platforms sooo much easier...

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the .NET Reference Source, it all seems intentional and on purpose:

```
public override Object DefaultValue { get { return GetDefaultValue(false); } }
public override Object RawDefaultValue { get { return GetDefaultValue(true); } }

private Object GetDefaultValue(bool raw)
{
    // ... Precheck
    object defaultValue = GetDefaultValueInternal(raw);
    // ... Postprocessing
    return defaultValue;
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
private Object GetDefaultValueInternal(bool raw)
{
    // ... Too long to include, but it contains "if (raw)"
    // ... a couple of times to do different things.
    return defaultValue;
}
```

*Source:*
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/parameterinfo.cs,565

With .NET being open source these days, if you think it should behave otherwise, just do a fix and submit a Pull Request ;-)

Comment: Honestly speaking, I'm used to checking mono sources for errors, not .net ;-) But your suggestion is perfectly valid, I came to similar conclusions as @tamir-vered - creation of an enum would not work in reflection-only context. Thanks for help!