# An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses option arguments in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to do a case statement for one of the properties when selecting an anonymous type in the first part and then convert it to a list of my return type (retList). In the retList part at the bottom when I set QuarterName = p.QuarterName I get the following error on the DatePart functions from the section above:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int categoryId)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
    var pList = (from p in context.Products
             where (p.CategoryId == proformaId)
             select new 
             {
                 Id = p.Id,
                 ProductName = p.ProductName,
                 QuarterName = pa.Quarter != "ExtraQuarter" ? "Q" + DateAndTime.DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, p.PurchaseDate) + 
                                               "-" + DateAndTime.DatePart(DateInterval.Year, p.PurchaseDate) : 
                                               "<b><i>" + p.Quarter + "</i></b>"

             }).ToList();

      var retList = from p in pList
                    select new ProformaAssumption()
                    {
                        Id = pa.Id,
                        ProductName = p.ProformaId,
                        QuarterName = p.QuarterName
                    };

      return retList;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum)

Answer (score 3):

The [`DatePart` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DatePart(v=vs.110).aspx) have additional, optional parameters. C# doesn't allow Expression Trees to leverage the optional parameters, so you'll need to provide the whole parameter list to each of these method calls.

According to the documentation, `FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday` and `FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1` are the values that would be used if you didn't provide a value for the optional parameters.

```
QuarterName = pa.Quarter != "ExtraQuarter" 
    ? "Q" +
        DateAndTime.DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, p.PurchaseDate,
            FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1) + 
        "-" + DateAndTime.DatePart(DateInterval.Year, p.PurchaseDate,
        FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1) 
    : "<b><i>" + p.Quarter + "</i></b>"
```