# Mock Elasticsearch client in NEST having problem with async search method

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, moq, nest

I am using NEST framework to do elastic search query in c#.

I am writing a simple unit test with Moq.

```
mockElasticClient.Setup(ec => ec.SearchAsync(
                                    It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<Relativity>,
                                            SearchDescriptor<Relativity>>>()))
                                    .ReturnsAsync(mockSearchResponse.Object);
```

THe above code throws `'An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments'`

the above code is working if i use Search instead of SearchAsync.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum
you have to pass the argment with default value manually.

Comment: Thank you. it really helped me.

Comment: In this below case how to do the mocking, could some one please help me over here, i am also facing same issue.







ISearchResponse<Organization> response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Organization>(s => s.Query(qry => qry.Raw(query))).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters in a mocked function should be accounted for. In this case as from the function definition

```
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   selector:
    //     A descriptor that describes the parameters for the search operation
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The type used to infer the index and typename as well describe the query strongly
    //     typed
    Task<ISearchResponse<T>> SearchAsync<T>(Func<SearchDescriptor<T>, ISearchRequest> selector = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class;
```

there are two parameters Func<SearchDescriptor, ISearchRequest>selector, and CancellationToken.

Mocking required that the CancellationToken Mocked as here below

```
mockElasticClient.Setup(x => x
            .SearchAsync(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<Relativity>, ISearchRequest>>(),It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(mockSearchResponse.Object);
```