# C# forcing to include optional parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following method from Microsoft:

```
public static string GetPathByAction(this LinkGenerator generator, 
   HttpContext httpContext, 
   string action = null, 
   string controller = null, 
   object values = null, 
   PathString? pathBase = null, 
   FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString), 
   LinkOptions options = null);
```

When I call this method without the last parameter I get the error:

```
  An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments
```

If a parameter is option why do I get such an error?

LinkGenerator is this class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2

**Update**

I am injecting LinkGenerator in a class as follows (I am not getting an error with this code because I am passing all parameters):

```
public class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler<Request, Response>> {

  private LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

  public RequestHandler(LinkGenerator linkGenerator) {

    _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;

  } 

  public async Task<Response> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

    List<File> files = getFiles();    

    // WORKS
    var url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(action: "GetByUserId", controller: "FileController", null, "", new HostString());

    // DOES NOT WORK
    var = await files
      .Select(x => new Response {
        Id = x.File.Id,
        Url = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(action: "GetByUserId", controller: "FileController", null, "", new HostString())
      }).ToListAsync();

    // Remaining code 

  }

}

public class File { 
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Can you include that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum)

Comment: @Ben Just added an update ...

Comment: `I am not getting an error with this code`. Could you include the code that is producing the error?

Comment: @devNull Try the following: Url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("GetByUserId", "FileController", null, new PathString(), new FragmentString())

Comment: @devNull I removed the part , new LinkOptions() part the end.

Comment: I was able to pin point the problem and post a better explanation. It seems when applying the method inside a Linq query I need to pass all parameters in LinkGenerator. If I use it outside Linq query I do not. any idea why? I have no idea what is going on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to:
https://github.com/Dresel/RouteLocalization/issues/6 and [An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum)

> you cannot use it with default arguments

Answer (score 0):

See also: [An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413583/an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-call-or-invocation-that-uses-optional-argum)

The simple answer is its not that calling the method without the optional parameter that is causing an error but how you're calling. If you're calling the method within a lambda it will only work if you specify the optional parameters.

Comment: I read that post but it is not clear to me ... So I need to pass all arguments even if they are optional? This makes no sense ... Even in Microsoft docs they are marked as Optional. any way around it?

Comment: You can call the function outside of an expression tree, or you could create a wrapper that calls the function and use that instead.